# Is it right to say "on the drive"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, prepositional-phrases, collocations

As we know we have these kinds of trip:

*bus trip*

*flight*

*cruise*

which we could use the preposition "on" for each one. For example:

What did you do on the cruise?

Did you have good time on the flight?

We have another kind of trip that is "drive" .I want to know if I could use "on" for " drive" as well. For example, can I say?:

**on the drive**

**We had a great time on our drive to Mexico.**

Comment: For your "good time" and "great time" examples, specifically, I myself would use "during." But "on our drive" is fine, too, if you're talking about "Oh, we saw the funniest thing on our drive down to Mexico."

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang - Sure, you could use _during_, but I'd probably use _on_. (To the OP): Absolutely you can say those things.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  This is a prepositional phrase and used in everyday speech.  "On the drive" means during the journey and is valid grammar.

Comment: Can yo give me reference. Book, website or anything.Because I didn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @Reza: I can't say I expect there even *is* a reference, as this is mostly English idiom. If you look at the usage of the two words discussed here, *on* and *during*, *on* is usually used for position, such as "the magazine is on the table" and *during* is used for time periods such as "I found myself dozing off during the meeting". It is for these uses that a reference would be used.

Those more commonplace examples aside, native speakers would typically in casual conversation use *on* when referring to a trip they took. It doesn't make sense when looked at from rules or word meaning.